# Can a person be infected with HIV viruses without contacting them by person-related stuffs?

Tags: hiv

We know that a person can be infected with HIV viruses when he/she has sexual relationship with those having HIV viruses (and very, very, very rarely, urine/defecation-related transmission) - but I wonder if there are other sources of HIV transmission - so for example, let's say during sexual relationship, some cuts on body (for example, inside vagina) occurred. Then even if the partner did not have HIV viruses, and a person afterwards does not sex with partners with HIV viruses, is there a chance that he/she may get HIV viruses, still?

Answer (score 3):

> let's say during sexual relationship, some cuts on body (for example, inside vagina) occurred. Then even if the partner did not have HIV viruses, and a person afterwards does not sex with partners with HIV viruses, is there a chance that he/she may get HIV viruses, still?

No, because there is no virus present in any of the people involved to be transmitted in this scenario.  HIV doesn't spontaneously occur in people.  It should also be noted that HIV is also highly transmissible in the blood.

Answer (score 1):

The virus must be present in one partner's body for transmission to occur.

Also, HIV can be transmitted through blood to blood contact.

There is currently a similar question/conversation that I have provided a link for here. It may provide some slightly more scientific answers than what I can:)
[How does a person get AIDS?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16919/how-does-a-person-get-aids)